# Error: UNC paths are not supported. Default to Windows Directory

Tags: python

I did not write this code, nor do I really work with Python, so please bear with me. The code below is supposed to run an update on one of our databases & create a few new files. When I try to run it, however, I get the error above. I think it works up to a certain point:

```
import arcpy
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
import xlwt
import glob


##set workspaces

os.chdir("//dotatufs04/crm/Public/temp/DDahms/Python/Update_MRS")

In_shp = "DraftHistoricProjectFootprints.gdb/DraftHistoricProjectFootprints"

##delete columns on Production_dot_project
os.system(r"\\dotatufs04\crm\Public\temp\DDahms\Python\Update_MRS\Scripts\run_macro_delete_columns.vbs")

##make joined shapefile and update status

try:
# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = "//dotatufs04/crm/Public/temp/DDahms/Python/Update_MRS"
arcpy.env.qualifiedFieldNames = False

# Set local variables    
layerName = "shapefile2"
joinTable = "PRODUCTION_DOTPF_PROJECT.xls/Sheet3$"
layerName2 = "tableview"
joinField1 = "AKSAS_Num_Txt"
joinField2 = "AKSAS_NUMBER"
join_tview = "test_tview"
output_shp = "DraftHistoricProjectFootprints.gdb/joined"


# Create a feature layer from the vegtype featureclass
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(In_shp,  layerName)
# Make Table view from .xls
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(joinTable, join_tview)


# Join the feature layer to a table
arcpy.AddJoin_management(layerName, joinField1, join_tview, joinField2)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(layerName, output_shp)

except Exception as err:
print(err.args[0])

#add "update" field
lstFields = arcpy.ListFields(output_shp)  

x = False  

for field in lstFields:  
if field.name == "update":   
    x = True  


if x <> "True":  
arcpy.AddField_management(output_shp, "updated", "STRING")

#calculate field
infield = "updated"
expression = 'myfunct(!AKSAS_Num_Txt!,!AKSAS_NUMBER!)'
codeblock = '''def myfunct(val1,val2):
if (val1 <> val2 or val1 == 'N/A' or val1 == '' or val2 == '' or val2 == 'N/A' or val1== None or val2 == None):
    return "Not Updated"
else:
    return "Updated"'''

arcpy.CalculateField_management(output_shp, infield, expression, "PYTHON_9.3", codeblock)    

#calculate field
infield2 = "AKSAS_Num_Txt"
infield3 = "AKSAS_NUMBER"
infield4 = "STATUS_CATEGORY"
infield5 = "Project_Status"
expression3 = 'myfunct3(!AKSAS_Num_Txt!,!AKSAS_NUMBER!,!Project_Status!,!STATUS_CATEGORY!)'
codeblock3 = '''def myfunct3(inpt,inpt2,inpt3,inpt4):
if (inpt <> inpt2 or inpt == 'N/A' or inpt == '' or inpt2 == '' or inpt2 == 'N/A' or inpt== None or inpt2 == None):
    result = inpt3
else:
    result = inpt4
return result'''

arcpy.CalculateField_management(output_shp, infield5, expression3, "PYTHON_9.3", codeblock3)

#delete fields
arcpy.DeleteField_management(output_shp, ["STATUS_CATEGORY","AKSAS_NUMBER"])

##export drafthistoricprojectfootprints to excel
Input_Table = "DraftHistoricProjectFootprints.gdb/joined"
Output_Excel_File = "DraftHistoricProjectFootprints.xls"
arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(Input_Table,Output_Excel_File)
```

The reason I say this works is because the "DraftHistoricProjectFootprints.xls" appears in the correct folder. Everything after this section of code does not:

```
##make csv sheets
os.system(r"\\dotatufs04\crm\Public\temp\DDahms\Python\Update_MRS\Scripts\run_macro_sort_construction.vbs")
wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="latin-1")
for filename in glob.glob(r"csv\*.csv"):
(f_path, f_name) = os.path.split(filename)
(f_short_name, f_extension) = os.path.splitext(f_name)
ws = wb.add_sheet(f_short_name)
spamReader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'))
for rowx, row in enumerate(spamReader):
    for colx, value in enumerate(row):
        ws.write(rowx, colx, value)
svstr = 'Projects_In_MRS.xls'
wb.save(svstr)



os.system(r"\\dotatufs04\crm\Public\temp\DDahms\Python\Update_MRS\Scripts\run_macro_sort_drafthistoricprojectfootprints.vbs")

##delete sheet3 and historic projects sheet
os.remove("csv/historicprojectsDraftHistoricProjectFootprints.csv")
os.remove("csv/Sheet3.csv")

##read cvs and make lists from data

with open(r"csv\completed.csv", 'rb') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
completed_list = list(reader)
completed_list = [el[2] for el in completed_list]


with open(r"csv\construction.csv", 'rb') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
construction_list = list(reader)
construction_list = [el[2] for el in construction_list]

with open(r"csv\design.csv", 'rb') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
design_list = list(reader)
design_list = [el[2] for el in design_list]

with open(r"csv\proposed.csv", 'rb') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
proposed_list = list(reader)
proposed_list = [el[2] for el in proposed_list]

with open(r"csv\suspended.csv", 'rb') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
suspended_list = list(reader)
suspended_list = [el[2] for el in suspended_list]

with open(r"csv\historicprojectscompleted.csv", 'rb') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
historic_completed_list = list(reader)
historic_completed_list =  [el[2] for el in historic_completed_list]

with open(r"csv\historicprojectsconstruction.csv", 'rb') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
historic_construction_list = list(reader)
historic_construction_list = [el[2] for el in historic_construction_list]

with open(r"csv\historicprojectsdesign.csv", 'rb') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
historic_design_list = list(reader)
historic_design_list = [el[2] for el in historic_design_list]

with open(r"csv\historicprojectsproposed.csv", 'rb') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
historic_proposed_list = list(reader)
historic_proposed_list = [el[2] for el in historic_proposed_list]

with open(r"csv\historicprojectssuspended.csv", 'rb') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
historic_suspended_list = list(reader)
historic_suspended_list = [el[2] for el in historic_suspended_list] 


##compare lists and write to csv
compare_completed = list(set(completed_list)-set(historic_completed_list))
if not compare_completed:
compare_completed.append("All Projects are in Shapefile!")
with open(r"compared_lists\compare_completed.csv", "w") as output:
writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
for val in compare_completed:
    writer.writerow([val])


compare_construction = list(set(construction_list)-set(historic_construction_list))
if not compare_construction:
compare_construction.append("All Projects are in Shapefile!")
with open(r"compared_lists\compare_construction.csv", "w") as output:
writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
for val in compare_construction:
    writer.writerow([val])

compare_design = list(set(design_list)-set(historic_design_list))
if not compare_design:
compare_design.append("All Projects are in Shapefile!")
with open(r"compared_lists\compare_design.csv", "w") as output:
writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
for val in compare_design:
    writer.writerow([val])

compare_proposed = list(set(proposed_list)-set(historic_proposed_list))
if not compare_proposed:
compare_proposed.append("All Projects are in Shapefile!")
with open(r"compared_lists\compare_proposed.csv", "w") as output:
writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
for val in compare_proposed:
    writer.writerow([val])

compare_suspended = list(set(suspended_list)-set(historic_suspended_list))
if not compare_suspended:
compare_suspended.append("All Projects are in Shapefile!")
with open(r"compared_lists\compare_suspended.csv", "w") as output:
writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
for val in compare_suspended:
    writer.writerow([val])

##combine csv to single workbook

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
for filename in glob.glob(r"compared_lists\*.csv"):
(f_path, f_name) = os.path.split(filename)
(f_short_name, f_extension) = os.path.splitext(f_name)
ws = wb.add_sheet(f_short_name)
spamReader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'))
for rowx, row in enumerate(spamReader):
    for colx, value in enumerate(row):
        ws.write(rowx, colx, value)
wb.save(r"Projects_Missing_from_DraftHistoricProjectFootprints.xls")

##put proj names on worksheet
os.system(r"\\dotatufs04\crm\Public\temp\DDahms\Python\Update_MRS\Scripts\run_macro_get_proj_names_to_missing_proj.vbs")

##change project status to proper (sentence) case

expression99 = '!Project_Status!.title()'
arcpy.CalculateField_management(output_shp, "Project_Status", expression99, "PYTHON_9.3")
```

Once this script runs, it should create/populate a few different documents as shown above, but instead, the error pops up and kills it. As mentioned above, I do not code in Python, so this is all new to me. Please explain your solutions like I'm five.

Thank you!

Comment: Indentation matters. If you have the right editor and/or editor settings, you can select the whole document, hit tab to move everything over, then copy, then undo. Then go to your stackoverflow post and paste the python code as-is, except with four spaces before it.

I assume you already googled the error message, so I won't do that.

You successfully execute os.system(unc_command_1), then later fail on os.system(unc_command_2)? If it works for one but not the other, then maybe one of the paths is wrong. But all I can do is guess. You may need to figure out how to run it in a debugger.

Comment: And obviously, if it is failing in your os.system call, then the error might have nothing to do with python.